# MAMP - Phpmyadmin (Error in processing, error code : 404, error not found)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have installed MAMP. When I click on the server in phpmyadmin. it shows

"Error in processing
Error code 404
Error not found".

I saw the same question in stackoverflow , but not a solution. Please let me know anyone who faced this problem and solved.

Thanks,

Comment: well, check where phpmyadmin is installed and what folder your server is looking in

Comment: I upgraded Mamp with the latest phpmyadmin. And it works now.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be linked to the outdated MAMP config file in the phpMyadmin directory.

I had the same issue, to fix it I backed up the old phpMyAdmin, downloaded a new one and then copied config.sample.inc.php to config.inc.php.

Edit the file so that it reads as follows:

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']      = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']  = 'root';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used MAMO Pro for Mac.You can go to the path below:

```
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin/
```

And open this file:

```
config.inc.php
```

find this line:

```
$cfg['DefaultTabServer'] = 'main.php';
```

Change **main.php** to **index.php**, like this:

```
$cfg['DefaultTabServer'] = 'index.php';
```

Or just comment this line use "#", like this:

```
#$cfg['DefaultTabServer'] = 'main.php';
```

This problem will be solved.